# How to use camera with React Native CLI

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a **Camera app**. I have tried several modules but with no success. Even `react-native-camera` crashes my apps.
Give me some advice, please !!
**Thank you!!**

Comment: Are you on an `Expo Managed Workflow`??

Comment: i'm using cli pro

Comment: Try [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)

Comment: Tks pro!!! I will try with expo :(

Comment: You can use `expo-camera` in both an `Expo Managed Workflow` as well as `Bare Workflow`